# Calling a parent method (prototype)

Tags: javascript, prototype

I have this code:

```
function Shape() {}

Shape.prototype.init = function(coords, color) {
    for(var i=0;i<coords.length;i++)
        var block= new Block (coords[i],color);
};

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {

};

// ============= I_Shape ================================
function I_Shape(center) {
     var coords = [new Point(center.x - 2, center.y),
               new Point(center.x - 1, center.y),
               new Point(center.x , center.y),
               new Point(center.x + 1, center.y)];

     Shape.prototype.init.call(this, coords, "blue");   

}
I_Shape.prototype = new Shape();
I_Shape.prototype.constructor = I_Shape;
```

I want to know why is there a 'init.call(...)' in the last line of the I_Shape function. Is it necessary(in the parent function the context is not used), or can be replaced by the following line?

```
Shape.prototype.init(coords,"blue");
```

Obviously in the first one you pass the context, but appart from that, what are the differences between those two?

Answer (score 0):

Good point.

As you've also said, [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is used to change the method's context, but given the fact that's not used inside your `init` method, both expressions are equivalent. So basically, given your specific example, you could effectively end up by calling `init` this way: `Shape.prototype.init(coords,"blue");`

Answer (score 0):

You should never assume that the superclass function doesn't need its context.

Just because the .init method doesn't use this now, doesn't mean it won't ever. As it is that function appears mostly useless because the created Block objects are created and will be immediately GCed because nothing else holds a reference to them.

Also, in theory you can just write:

```
this.init(coords, "blue")
```

and the prototype mechanism will automatically call the method from the super class without you naming it explicitly.

If you subsequently add an `init` method to `I_Shape` then *that's* the place you should call the superclass's `init` method from, rather than from the constructor.